# Google Analytics E-Commerce Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, magento-1.9

unfortunaltely our Ecommerce Tracking isnt working. Google-Support refered us to this forum, since they couldnt give us an solution for this problem.

Following Code is added in our Success Page:

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE UNIVERSAL ANALYTICS CODE -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                        ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '200017345',
'affiliation': 'TEST',
'revenue': '60.5000',
'tax': '3.9600',
'shipping': '0.0000'
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '200017345',
'sku': '70049--500',
'name': 'Hot Honey Cashews (68022)',
'category': '',
'price': '15.1400',
'quantity': '1.0000'
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '200017345',
'sku': '100209--500',
'name': 'Nordic Deluxe (68023)',
'category': '',
'price': '22.9000',
'quantity': '1.0000'
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '200017345',
'sku': '100209--200',
'name': 'Nordic Deluxe (68024)',
'category': '',
'price': '9.2500',
'quantity': '2.0000'
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
        //]]>
        </script>
        <!-- END GOOGLE UNIVERSAL ANALYTICS CODE -->
```

Is this code correct?
I hope you guys have an solution for this. Thank you very much in advance.

The following tracker is placed more above in the header section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX, 'auto');

    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Did you enable ecommerce tracking in the View configuration? Also, check with GA Debugger or the dev console to see if you can see any hits going through with your ecom information.

Answer (score 1):

You did not create a tracker:

> ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

So Google Analytics would not know where to send the data to. This must go before the `ga('require',` and obviously you would substitute a proper account id.

Also check your view settings if e-ecommerce tracking is enabled and set to the proper version (since you use standard e-commerce tracking you must not enable the "enhanced e-commerce" setting).

Comment: Is it generally a problem, that the tracker is placed more above in the header section? - The e-commerce tracking was already disabled